# Having problems running game in Java Slick library and lwjgl

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, slick2d

I am working in creating a game and I am using Slick and lwjgl. My java version is jdk1.7.0_79. This is my code:

```
package javagame;
 import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
 import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
 import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
 import org.newdawn.slick.state.GameState;
 import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
/*
 * First we import the things we need
*/
public class Game extends StateBasedGame{
public static final String gamename="Ham Blaster";
public static final int menu =0;
public static final int play =1;
/*
* Startup things of our game
*/
public Game(String gamename) {
    super(gamename);
    this.addState((GameState) new Menu(menu));
    this.addState((GameState) new Play(play));

}
/*
 * Here we create the two states or screens of our game.
 */
public void initStatesList (GameContainer gc)throws SlickException{
    this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
    this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
    this.enterState(menu);
}
/*
 * Here we set the display settings and this is going to be our main method.
 */
public static void main(String[]args){
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc=new AppGameContainer(newGame(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 360, false);
        appgc.start();
    }catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

It gives me error on newGame(gamename)) saying that this method is undefined for the type Game. Since I am using Eclipse it gives me some instructions when there is an error and it instructed me to create a method for it. Eclipse created the method and this the method code:

```
    private static org.newdawn.slick.Game newGame(String gamename2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

What should I write inside of it?
Also here is the code of the 2 other screens:
Play screen:

```
package javagame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

 public class Play extends Exception {
  public Play(int play){
  }
  public void init (GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws Play {
  }
  /* 
   Render is used to draw things
   */
  public void render (GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)throws Play {
  }
  /*
   Update is used to update the images in your game
   */
  public void update (GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g, int delta)throws Play{  
  }
  public int getID(){
      return 1;
}
}
```

And the menu screen:

```
package javagame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

 public class Menu extends Exception {
  public Menu(int menu) {}
      public void init (GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws Menu {
      }
      public void render (GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)throws Menu {
      }
      public void update (GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g, int delta)throws Menu{  
      }
      public int getID(){
          return 0;
}

}
```

Screenshot of the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BamS.png

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple. Instead of writing `appgc=new AppGameContainer(newGame(gamename));`, you need to write `appgc=new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));`

Comment: still console doesn't print out anything

Comment: Does that window open? Does eclipse give you an error when you click the Run button?

Comment: Click on the arrow next to the Run button, then select Run As from the Menu and click "Java Application"

Comment: It doesn't have the option to run Java Application maybe that's the problem

Comment: Try openning the class with the main method and then run as Java Application

Comment: it ran as a java application but still gave me errors

Comment: I am just posting it so everybody can see it

Comment: Which version of LWJGL are you using and which version of Slock-util? If you are using LWJGL 3, then try using LWJGL 2 instead

Comment: it worked but it still gives me error on line 37 and 19

Comment: line 19: this.addState((GameState) new Menu(menu));
line 37:    appgc=new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javagame.Menu cannot be cast to org.newdawn.slick.state.GameState
 at javagame.Game.<init>(Game.java:19)
 at javagame.Game.main(Game.java:37)

Comment: In line 19 you are trying to cast Menu to a GameState. But Menu doesn't extend GameState and so Java throws an error. If you replaced Exception with GameState then the error should go away. If that works do the same with the Play class. Also since Menu and Play are both extending GameState you don't need to cast them to a GameState when you add them.

Comment: Like this?   this.addState((Exception) new Menu(menu));
  this.addState((Exception) new Play(play));

Comment: addState takes in a GameState not an Exception and that is why you get an error. That code should look like this `this.addState(new Menu(menu)); this.addState(new Play(play));` and both Menu and Play need to extend GameState instead of Excpetion